# How to set-up multiple sub-styles in a custom style with icCube latest reporting?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

In 5.x you could set-up multiple sub-styles within a style (see image).
How can something similar be achieved in 6.5? [image: example sub-styles to choose from in icCube 5.x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the advanced properties (bottom) of the General submenu :

[image]